# React component not rendering correctly after await call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack

i have html template i purchased at themeforest.net im trying to convert it to webpack and react every thing works fine now but there is weird bug when ever i make await call in componentDidMount the page didnt render correctly

```
let res = await axios({
method: "get",
url: "http://localhost:8080/api/main/mainProducts",
});

this.setState({ allProducts: res.data });
```

when i comment the await call
and setstate to static data

```
let allProducts = [
{
//array data
},
]
this.setState({ allProducts: allProducts });
```

its render correctly. here is the component

```
export class MainComponent extends React.Component<{}, any> {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      allProducts: [],
    };
  }
  async componentDidMount() {
    let res = await axios({
      method: "get",
      url: "http://localhost:8080/api/main/mainProducts",
    });
    this.setState({ allProducts: res.data });
  }
  render(): any {
    return (
      <div className="product-4 product-m no-arrow">
        {this.state.allProducts.map((x) => (
          <div key={x.id} className="product-box product-wrap">
            <div className="img-wrapper">
              <div className="lable-block">
                <span className="lable3">new</span>{" "}
                <span className="lable4">on sale</span>
              </div>
              <div className="front">
                <a href={"/product/" + x.id}>
                  {x.images.map((image) =>
                    image.main.toString() === "true" ? (
                      <img
                        className="img-fluid blur-up lazyload bg-img"
                        key={image.id}
                        src={`/public/productImages/${x.id.toString()}/${
                          image.imageName
                        }`}
                      ></img>
                    ) : (
                      ""
                    )
                  )}
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
      // long html lines here 
      // ...
    );
  }
}
```

webpack config

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
  entry: path.join(__dirname, "src/index.tsx"),
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader"],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(svg|gif|jpg|png|eot|woff|woff2|ttf)$/,
        use: [
        'url-loader',
        ],
      },  
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ["babel-loader"],
      },
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        loader: "ts-loader",
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        use: ["ts-loader"],
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".js"],
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: path.resolve(__dirname, "src", "index.html"),
       filename: "./index.html",
    }),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: "jquery",
      jQuery: "jquery",
    }),
  ],
  output: {
    path: __dirname + "/dist/",
    filename:  "index.js",
    publicPath: '/'
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    proxy: {
      "/api": {
        target: "http://localhost:5050",
        pathRewrite: { "^/api": "" },
      },
    },
  },
  mode: "development",
};
```

entry point index.tsx

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { MainComponent } from "./views/user/main/main";
import { Bottom } from "./views/user/layout/bottom";
import { Top } from "./views/user/layout/top";
import "core-js/stable";
import "regenerator-runtime/runtime";

import "./helpers/css"; //css imports of the html template

render(
  <Router>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/" exact>
        <>
          <Top />
          <MainComponent />
          <Bottom />
        </>
      </Route>
    </Switch>
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById("r")
);

import "./helpers/js"; //js imports of the html template
```

and most importantly css and js imports

css.tsx

```
import "/public/assets/css/fontawesome.css";
import "/public/assets/css/slick.css";
import "/public/assets/css/slick-theme.css";
import "/public/assets/css/animate.css";
import "/public/assets/css/themify-icons.css";
import "/public/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import "/public/assets/css/bootstrap4-toggle.min.css";
import "/public/assets/css/jquery.lazyloadxt.spinner.css";
import "/public/assets/css/color5.css";
import "/public/assets/css/site.css";
```

js.tsx

```
import "/public/assets/js/jquery-ui.min.js";
import "/public/assets/js/jquery.exitintent.js";
import "/public/assets/js/exit.js";
// @ts-ignore
window.Popper = require("/public/assets/js/popper.min.js");
import "/public/assets/js/slick.js";
import "/public/assets/js/menu.js";
import "/public/assets/js/lazysizes.min.js";
import "/public/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js";
import "/public/assets/js/bootstrap4-toggle.min.js";
import "/public/assets/js/bootstrap-notify.min.js";
import "/public/assets/js/fly-cart.js";
import "/public/assets/js/script.js";
import "/public/scripts/layout.js";
```

i suspect its something to do with slick library
ive tried import() slick js and css files after setstate but it doesnt work

```
this.setState({ allProducts: res.data }, () => {
      import("../../../../public/assets/css/slick.css");
      import("../../../../public/assets/css/slick-theme.css");
      import("../../../../public/assets/js/slick.js");
    });
```

i have also tried re import the whole css and js files but also doesnt work
i have also tried many other things like using ajax instead of axios but it give the exact same bug ive also tried this

```
axios({
      method: "get",
      url: "http://localhost:8080/api/main/mainProducts",
    }).then((x) => {
      this.setState({ allProducts: x.data });
    });
```

no await here but its same bug also.
a picture of when its render correctly
[image: a picture of when its render correctly]

wrong render
[image: wrong render]

any help would be really appreciated.
thanks !

Comment: usefull article about this topic
https://reactjs.org/docs/concurrent-mode-suspense.html#traditional-approaches-vs-suspense

Comment: thanks <Suspense fallback={<p>loading...</p>}><MainComponent /></Suspense> didnt fix the problem im using react 17

Comment: might be problem with JS in  ./helpers/js, if you do async call you actually give chance to JS in ./helpers/js to get executed before you in fact render content of <MainComponent/> contrary to situation when you provide state to <MainConponent> statically at first Render

Comment: ive tried comment js import and do dynamic import after setstate this.setState({ allProducts: res.data },()=>{
      import("../../../helpers/js")
    }); but half of the page didnt render

Comment: i saw it, but i am not sure, if callback in setState is called in commit phases where DOM is updated. I would expected that is called in render phase, when DOM still not updated though.

Comment: interesting , how to do import after components are fully loaded ? any suggestion please thanks

Comment: ive tried dynamic import this time in components render callback render(..., document.getElementById("r"), () => import("./helpers/js")); and import after setTimeout it doesnt work

Comment: Please notice, that i haven't answered to this question in advance. Problem is, if i am right, you are trying integrate libs, framework for static DOM to React, which is possible, but hard to do properly. Check official guide https://reactjs.org/docs/integrating-with-other-libraries.html.  As for you question, i believe componentDidUpdate is called after second and following DOM updates. But you should use HTML template only as visual guidance, and rework all content to React ready libs

Comment: you are right, i found react version of same library and all i did is wrap product div to <Slider> and it works ! i take that as answer thanks !